# Estimating RAM cost accurately

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I'm currently working on a 2D game android java.

I'm trying to avoid the common OOM we all deal with when working with bitmaps.

To do so, during the first launch, I estimate the max RAM usage on my application and downscale the bitmaps according to the results: I calculate the byte size of every bitmap by doing **width * height * 2** (I'm using **RGB_565** ), I also double the result for heaviests sprites to take account of the G-Buffer.

The problem is, my result is far from the real usage. On my device: **~60MB** estimated, and **~100MB** in real usage. 
The calculation gets accurate when I double the estimated byte size for every bitmaps.

Am I missing something ? Do we really need to double count the space taken for every bitmap ?

Comment: Since you have an implementation, why not use the memory profiler and see what's actually taking the space rather than estimating?  Also remember that bitmaps aren't the only things that take up large amounts of memory.

Comment: What doe you mean by MO?

Comment: You don't need to calculate all the space for the graphics unless you need them all at once. When are not used, are stored in the native compressed format.

Comment: @WalterPalladino, my images are stored in Bitmap class, so yes I need to calculate the size of all the uncompressed images that are gonna be stored in the same time.

Comment: In relationship to the error you found, there are multiple small images or atlases? If there are multiple images, it is possible the difference is related to the size of the structure in relationship with the size of the image. One way to optimize storage is using atlases. Could this work for you?

Comment: what do you mean by atlases? yes there's a lot of images each stored in an individually Bitmap class